# Starting with Python and GUIs

Tags: python, user-interface, generic-programming, command-line-interface

A friend of mine encouraged me to start programming in Python to do "lots" of things in a kinda "easier" way. I already have a base of C. I'd like to start doing some GUI stuff in python (even if I just started learning it) just to do something "more serious" than the classic CLI applications. What do you recommend me to do? What are the differences between CLI programming and GUI programming? What should my first step be? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you looking for project ideas? Recommendations for a GUI toolkit for Python? GUI specific design patterns? Links to resources? Please try to be more specific.

Comment: How do I start making GUI applications? What's the "philosophy" underneath GUI programming? Thanks.